# Load, Read XML file but save become file text with spacing

Tags: php, xml

I have just load the xml file and save it immediately but then it become text file.
My XML structure is simple here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentInfo>
    <Content>
        <PlayerID>P1</PlayerID>
        <TVID>TV1</TVID>
        <TVStatus>0</TVStatus>
    </Content>  
</ContentInfo>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<?php
ob_start();
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xml->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('TV_Status.xml');
htmlentities($xml->save('TV_Status.xml'));
header("Refresh: 120;url='index.php'");
 ?>
```

It automatically changes to text files although it is still ending with xml file and still can be edit.

Comment: What do you mean with "it becomes a text file"? XML is text, so that should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, edited text with spacing not xml format

Answer (score 0):

XML files are text files. There should be no problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and the new written file looks almost exactly the same as the source file.

XML is text.

You should remove `ob_start();`. If you mean that the format is not like you want it to be then you should play around with this part

```
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

a bit.

Answer (score 0):

XML files are text files. Text files with a specific syntax that an application can parse. By default if you send data to the browser, PHP will send an additional information (HTTP header) that the data is HTML. If a browser receives data as HTML it will try to parse and render it. XML syntax uses the a comparable syntax, so the XML tags get parsed as HTML, but ignored as unknown HTML tags. The browser displays the text content of the XML file.

You can change that behavior be sending different content type headers:

Send as XML:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
readfile('TV_Status.xml');
```

Send as text:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile('TV_Status.xml');
```

You don't need to load and parse an XML file for this, you can just read and pass it to the browser using `readfile()`.